# Implementing "reply to notification from lock screen" in iOS 10

Tags: ios

We have a messaging app that aims to display notifications when it receives messages when phone is locked from remote user, and let local user enter text from lock screen, and send the message. How do I implement this? Is UNUserNotificationCenter in iOS 10 the way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is lack of well-structured info in internet, although it's very good feature, implemented in serious messenger apps.

You should start with `UNNotificationContentExtension` to show custom UI for received Push Notification. Take any available example on internet and implement it like you want. Pay attention on bundle ID - it should be `com.yourapp.yourextension`. When done, you'll have the main app and the extension widget in Xcode.

In the main app set up registration for Push Notifications in iOS10 manner:

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        guard granted else { return }
        let replyAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "ReplyAction", title: "Reply", options: [])
        let openAppAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "OpenAppAction", title: "Open app", options: [.foreground])
        let quickReplyCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "QuickReply", actions: [replyAction, openAppAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([quickReplyCategory])
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
```

All magic happens in `UNTextInputNotificationAction` custom action that you add to your Push Notifications handler.

To complete setting up Push Notifications add this param in your **extension** `Info.plist`: `NSExtension -> NSExtensionAttributes -> UNNotificationExtensionCategory: "QuickReply"`

It's all about setting up. To try it, use `Pusher` tool and configure Push Notification in this manner:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert":"Trigger quick reply",
        "category":"QuickReply"
    }
}
```

At least you have to catch the notification in your widget. It happens in `func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification)` in your widget class:

```
func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    let message = notification.request.content.body
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // populate data from received Push Notification in your widget UI...
}
```

And if user responds to received Push Notification, your widget will trigger the following callback:

```
func didReceive(_ response: UNNotificationResponse, completionHandler completion: @escaping (UNNotificationContentExtensionResponseOption) -> Void) {
    if response.actionIdentifier == "ReplyAction" {
        if let textResponse = response as? UNTextInputNotificationResponse {
            // Do whatever you like with user text response...
            completion(.doNotDismiss)
            return
        }
    }
    completion(.dismiss)
}
```

Comment: I have followed your steps...And it worked like a charm..But I am stuck at "ReplyAction". I want to call API at ReplyAction. Is it possible to call API in notification content extension? And if yes could u please give me lead how I can achieve that?

Comment: @bittu Sure, you may run any code there. When calling API request it meant you have some completion handler where you get response from API. In that handler you call `yourNotificationContentExtension.completionHandler(.dismiss)`. Another question is how to pass API credentials from the main app to the extension - you should use shared `User Defaults` for that.

Comment: @bittu I am also trying to call API on action button but i am getting netweork lost error in alamofire...