# Open input text field when clicked on notification not on notification action

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swift5

Here, I am trying to implement "reply from notification" feature like WhatsApp,

I am able to open text field from action button but it takes few taps to do that.
When you click (single tap) on the notification got from WhatsApp (while phone is locked) it will directly opens the text field where I can add reply message.

Currently when I click on the notification (while phone is locked) it will directly opens the app which I don't want to be happen. **App should not be launched.**

Also I have used Notification Content Extension too.

Comment: Have you seen the answer provided on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39583736/4056108)

Comment: Yes, I did and code provided in this link is using notification action to open the text field but I want that to happen on notification tap